# Fill NaN by adding successive number within groups in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe such as

```
Groups NAME Number
G1     A    1
G1     B    2
G1     D    NaN
G1     D    NaN 
G1     I    3
G1     H    NaN 
G2     E    1 
G2     E    1
G2     F    NaN
G2     J    2
G3     K    NaN
G3     L    1
```

and I would like to fill the NaN values within groups by completing numbers

For instance, `D` in `G1` gets the `Number 4` since 1,2 & 3 are already present.
Then H in `G1` gets the `Number 5` ect...

At the and I should get ;

```
Groups NAME Number
G1     A    1
G1     B    2
G1     D    4
G1     D    4
G1     I    3
G1     H    5
G2     E    1 
G2     E    1
G2     F    3
G2     J    2
G3     K    2
G3     L    1
```

Does someone have and idea please ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby` + `ngroup` to label each Group/Name with nulls with an increasing integer. Then we subtract off the min `ngroup` within the group (to determine how much to add) and add the max Number that already exists within the group.

Then we `fillna` with this Series.

```
s = df[df['Number'].isnull()].groupby(['Groups', 'NAME']).ngroup()
#2     0      #<- G1/D  (Series index is DataFrame index)
#3     0      #<- G1/D  
#5     1      #<- G1/H 
#8     2      #<- G2/F
#10    3      #<- G3/K

to_fill = (s - s.groupby(df['Groups']).transform('min') + 1
           + df.groupby('Groups')['Number'].transform('max'))
#0     NaN
#1     NaN
#2     4.0
#3     4.0
#4     NaN
#5     5.0
#6     NaN
#7     NaN
#8     3.0
#9     NaN
#10    2.0
#11    NaN

df['Number'] = df['Number'].fillna(to_fill, downcast='infer')
#   Groups NAME  Number
#0      G1    A       1
#1      G1    B       2
#2      G1    D       4
#3      G1    D       4
#4      G1    I       3
#5      G1    H       5
#6      G2    E       1
#7      G2    E       1
#8      G2    F       3
#9      G2    J       2
#10     G3    K       2
#11     G3    L       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `pd.factorize()`

```
df['Number_New'] = df.sort_values('Number').groupby('Groups')['NAME'].transform(lambda x: (pd.factorize(x)[0])+1)
```